# ValidationAttribute.FormatErrorMessage throwing Input string was not in a correct format error

Tags: c#, string, validationattribute

I have written a custom attribute. In the error message I have special characters. due to these special characters, ValidationAttribute.FormatErrorMessage(GetDisplayName()) throwing Input string was not in a correct format error.

My error message is @"Your characters should be in: ^_{}~".

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Is this string the value set as `ErrorMessageString`? Do you override `FormatErrorMessage`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because of {}. It has special meaning in c#. So you have to use escape character for that.
ex:
(ErrorMessage = "Your characters should be in: !#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[]^_{{|}}~"

So for escaping {, you have to use double {.